Moving around a zero measure set without intersections
Given a zero-Lebesgue-measure Borel subset $A$ of $B$, the open unit ball of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (or more generally a zero-volume-measure Borel subset $A$ of a smooth complete Riemannian manifold $M$ with finite volume), is it possible to "move it around" countably many times without any intersection?
To be precise: suppose $A \subset B$ has $0$ Lebesgue measure (we can also suppose its diameter to be as small as needed). I want to know if there exists a countable family $(\varphi_i)_i$ of smooth "nice" diffeomorphisms of $B$ such that the sets $A_i:=\varphi_i(A)$ are pair-wise disjoint and they also do not intersect $A$. By "nice" diffeomorphism I mean that it must be measure preserving and equal to the identity outside a compact subset of $B$.
This property seems to be true in simple cases as $n=1$ and $A$ is a point, or $n=2$ and $A$ is a segment. I am wondering if this is the case in general.
Any reference or direct proof would be highly appreciated!

If A has points which are arbitrarly close to $\partial B$, then a diffeomorphism that is the identity outside of a compact set fix infinite points of $A$, so $\varphi(A)\cap A\neq \emptyset$. Therefore you have to relax the hypothesis a bit: or $A$ has compact closure in $B$ or the diffeomorphisms don't need to be the identity outside of a compact set. Moreover, since $B$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$ it's the same to ask the question in $\mathbb R^n$ (the conjugate of a measure preserving map is still measure preserving).
